# How to set previous 3 months in php?

Tags: php, date

> Currently i am getting this output with my for loop to view next 3
>   months by current month:

```
$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m',strtotime($endDate)), 1, date('Y',strtotime($endDate)));
for ($i = 0; $i > 3; $i++) 
{
    $to_date = date('F Y', strtotime($i++.' month', $this_month)) . '';
}
```

[image]

As you can see in image i am getting march-2018 to may-2018 etc. Now i want if i get march-2018 then i want to display Jan-2018 to march-2018 etc.How to get this type data.

Comment: `strtotime("-3 month")` should give what you need? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below approuch will loop and modify the `DateTime` object while doing so. It will echo your date each loop and thus display each month for a period of 3 months in the past.

```
// Date as a string
$sDate = '2018-04-01';

// Create a DateTime object
$oDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $sDate);

// Get the previous 3 months
for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $oDate->modify('-1 month');
    echo $oDate->format('F Y');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateTime::sub()`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.sub.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php)

like this :

```
$date = new DateTime($endDate); // create the dateTime object
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P3M')) // substract 3 months to this date
$to_date =  $date->format('F Y');
```

Comment: ... or use [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) instead of `sub()`.